# Construct a tree from a given array

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, tree

I would like to construct a graph from a given array and root where the node is described below,

```
static class TreeNode {

    private int value;
    private ArrayList<TreeNode> children; 

    public TreeNode(int nodeValue) {
        this.value = nodeValue;
        this.children = new ArrayList<TreeNode>();
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public void addChild(TreeNode child) {
        this.children.add(child);
    }

    public ArrayList<TreeNode> getChildren() {
        return this.children;
    } 
}
```

An array provided below to construct the graph,

```
T[0] = 1
T[1] = 2
T[2] = 3
T[3] = 3
T[4] = 2
T[5] = 1
T[6] = 4
```

Array T describes a network of cities if T[P] = Q and P ≠ Q, then there is a direct road between cities P and Q. If the index of 2 is root, then the graph is provided below,

```
     2 - 3
    / \
   1   4
  / |  |
 0  5  6
```

Obviously, I can do it manually for the given array,

```
    final int N = 7;
    TreeNode[] nodes = new TreeNode[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        nodes[i] = new TreeNode(i);
    }


    TreeNode root = nodes[2];

    root.addChild(nodes[1]);
    root.addChild(nodes[3]);
    root.addChild(nodes[4]);


    nodes[1].addChild(nodes[0]);
    nodes[1].addChild(nodes[5]);

    nodes[4].addChild(nodes[6]);
```

How do I construct programmatically when I have given an array and K value? Please help.

Comment: What have you tryed?

Comment: @nicomp I'm still trying to write it properly. I will update here when I'm done

Comment: @nicomp I tried  and provided an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you construct the `TreeNode[]` array, it's easy:

```
TreeNode root = null;
for (int i=0; i<T.length; ++i) {
    if (T[i] == i) { // if it's a root node
        //TODO: Test for multiple root nodes here
        root = nodes[i];
    } else {
        nodes[T[i]].addChild(nodes[i]);
    }
}
```

I would add a `private TreeNode parent;` object to the `TreeNode` class, initialize it to `null` and set it to the parent reference in the `addChild` method.  That's handy to have during debug, even if you don't need it for the first use of this class.  Maybe you'll need it later.

Comment: I would like to accept your answer, but the output is not completely correct. I run the code and get:

`The root = 3
Parent 3 has children = 2
Parent 2 has children = 1
Parent 2 has children = 4
Parent 1 has children = 0
Parent 1 has children = 5
Parent 4 has children = 6`

The root is 2 and the Parent 3 has children = 2 is not correct and actually opposite is true

Comment: @Arefe This does not really follow from the data that you provided. `T[2] = 3` says that 3 is a parent of 2, so 2 cannot be a root. And `T[3] = 3` shows that 3 has no parent, so it is a root. Are there some additional rules and parameters that make 2 a root? If so, what if 3 was really a part of a tree, eg. `T[3] = 7; T[7] = 8; T[8] = 8; T[9] = 8; T[10] = 9;` and so on...?

Comment: Yes, the root index `K` is given where you will need to start. So, even if T[children] = parent, if T[K] = V then the K is the parent of V. How do I change the code now

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over all nodes,
for each node get the node's value and add the current node to the node at the value.

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    nodes[nodes[i].getValue()].addChild(nodes[i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I write an answer, however, it's not showing all the children. The code is provided below,

```
public class App {

    static class TreeNode {

        private int value;
        private ArrayList<TreeNode> children;

        public TreeNode(int nodeValue) {
            this.value = nodeValue;
            this.children = new ArrayList<TreeNode>();
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return this.value;
        }

        public void addChild(TreeNode child) {
            this.children.add(child);
        }

        public ArrayList<TreeNode> getChildren() {
            return this.children;
        }
    }


    public static TreeNode buildGraph(int[] T, int K) {

        final int N = T.length;

        TreeNode[] nodes = new TreeNode[N];

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            nodes[i] = new TreeNode(i);
        }

        /*
            T[0] = 1
            T[1] = 2
            T[2] = 3
            T[3] = 3
            T[4] = 2
            T[5] = 1
            T[6] = 4

                 2 - 3
                / \
               1   4
              / |  |
             0  5  6
        * */

        TreeNode root = nodes[K];

        Queue<TreeNode> queue = new LinkedList<>();
        queue.offer(root);

        boolean[] visited = new boolean[N];

        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {

            TreeNode node = queue.poll();
            int index = node.getValue();

            visited[index] = true;

            // T[3] = 3 is a leaf with no further connection to develop
            if (index == T[index]) {
                continue;
            }

            // 2 != 3 for the root node and we havent visited node 3 earlier
            if (index != T[index] && !visited[T[index]]) {

                node.addChild(nodes[T[index]]);
                queue.offer(nodes[T[index]]);
            }

            int left = 0, right = N - 1;

            while (left < index && right > index) {

                if (T[left] == index) {

                    node.addChild(nodes[left]);
                    queue.offer(nodes[left]);
                }

                if (T[right] == index) {

                    node.addChild(nodes[right]);
                    queue.offer(nodes[right]);
                }

                left++;
                right--;
            }
        }

        return root;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] T = new int[7];

        T[0] = 1;
        T[1] = 2;
        T[2] = 3;
        T[3] = 3;
        T[4] = 2;
        T[5] = 1;
        T[6] = 4;

        TreeNode root = buildGraph(T, 2);

        System.out.println("The root = " + root.getValue());

        Queue<TreeNode> queue = new LinkedList<>();
        queue.offer(root);

        while(!queue.isEmpty()){

            TreeNode node = queue.poll();

            ArrayList<TreeNode> children = node.getChildren();

            for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {

                TreeNode child = children.get(i);
                queue.offer(child);

                System.out.println("Parent "+ node.getValue()+ " has children = "+ child.getValue());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At the time I run, I get output like,

```
The root = 2
Parent 2 has children = 3
Parent 2 has children = 1
Parent 1 has children = 0
```

Anyone can help me to correct how do I miss the other children?

### Update

I write it based on the other answer which seems simpler.

```
public static TreeNode buildGraph1(int[] T, int K) {

        final int N = T.length;

        TreeNode[] nodes = new TreeNode[N];

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            nodes[i] = new TreeNode(i);
        }

        /*
       T[children] = parent if the children != K

            T[0] = 1
            T[1] = 2
            T[2] = 3
            T[3] = 3
            T[4] = 2
            T[5] = 1
            T[6] = 4

                 2 - 3
                / \
               1   4
              / |  |
             0  5  6
        * */

        TreeNode root = nodes[K];
        int value = root.getValue();

        if (T[K] != K) {
            nodes[K].addChild(nodes[T[K]]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < T.length; ++i) {

            if (K == i) {
                continue;
            }

            if (T[i] != i) {
                nodes[T[i]].addChild(nodes[i]);
            }
        }

        return root;
    }
```

The output is provided below:

```
The root = 2
Parent 2 has children = 3
Parent 2 has children = 1
Parent 2 has children = 4




Parent 1 has children = 0
Parent 1 has children = 5


Parent 4 has children = 6
```